# SQL . Tabla con promedios trimestrales a partir de datos mensuales

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Tengo una tabla con campos de datos numéricos mensuales (enero a diciembre) para varios años.
Quiero generar una nueva tabla que contenga los promedios trimestrales para esos campos numéricos para cada año, de modo que la tabla generada debiera verse así:

"**Año**" "**Trimestre**" "**Promedio Campo1**" "**Promedio Campo2**" "**Promedio CampoN**"

Tengo experiencia limitada con los comandos `SELECT, SELECT INTO`y`UPDATE`, pero no veo cómo puedo producir ese resultado.

Aclaración adicional:
Mi tabla abarca información mensual para varios años, por lo que se ve de este modo:

Año   Mes     Campo1    Campo2    CampoN
2015   1      100        200       300
2015  ................................... (meses 2 a 11)
2015  12      130        225       315
2016   1      135        215       295
2016  ................................... (meses 2 a 11)
2017   1      140        250       320
2017  ................................... (meses 2 a 11)
2018   1      160        270       340
2017  ................................... (meses 2 a 7)
2018   8      170        275       350

Yo pretendo obtener promedios trimestrales, es decir, el promedio de enero-marzo, abril-junio, julio-septiembre y octubre-diciembre de cada año.

No veo cómo puedo obtener en una sola consulta (query) toda esta información.

Gracias.

Comment: Coloca la estructura de tu tabla por favor.

Comment: Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis es esta para hallar el promedio es esta:

```
SELECT AVG(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

Acomódala a tus columnas y nos cuentas si funcionó.

Comment: No, no funciona, por que lo que necesito son promedios trimestrales. Es decir, son varios promedios, no uno solo. Supongo que tendría que recurrir a una macro en MS ACCESS para poder realizar lo que necesito. Pero no estoy familiarizado con Visual Basic para MS ACCESS.